# Autocomplete with Next/Previous button

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I am creating a autocomplete textbox for a application for touch screen device  [jquery autocomlete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete). The scrollbar in the autocomplete is not so user friendly so i was suppose to give another option. Is it possible to include Next/Prev button inside autocomplete? or Is there any other good option for this issue?

Geetha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no easy method to do paging in jquery autocomplete. As you don't want to show the scrollbar, you can specify the `max` and `scrollHeight` properties such that it will show enough options without any scrollbar. Here `max` is the maximum number of results it will show.

```
$("div.autocomplete").autocomplete('results.aspx',{ 
   max:10;
   scrollHeight:250
});
```

If you desperately want paging, why don't you use [Jquery FlexBox](http://www.fairwaytech.com/flexbox/flexbox-demos/). In Flexbox you can implement paging very easily.

```
 $('div.autocomplete').flexbox('results.aspx', {  
     showArrow: false 
     paging: {  
         pageSize: 10
     }  
 });
```

As flexbox by default shows the arrow sign on the right of the input box, you need to set `showArrow` to `false` to remove that and make it look like an autocomplete rather than a combobox. Here `pageSize` specifies the maximum number of result per page.

Answer (score 1):

FlexBox in the accepted answer is apparently no longer available.

However, I did find another option which looks very good and is available under the MIT License.

[jquery.ajax-combobox](https://github.com/sutara79/jquery.ajax-combobox)